# How to fix error "Can't invoke 'findObjectInBackgroundWithBlock' with an argument list of type ((AnyObject!, NSError!) -> Void)

Tags: swift, parse-platform

For below code, getting `Can't invoke 'findObjectInBackgroundWithBlock' with an argument list of type ((AnyObject!, NSError!) -> Void)` error and not able to run the parse query in background. Any thoughts?

```
var data = Query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock(
        {(object:AnyObject!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

})
```

Comment: objects, plural.  Try `objects: [AnyObject]!`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3) you need to call the function by:

```
var data = Query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({(objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

})
```

And if you are using swift 1.1 (Xcode 6.1, 6.2) you need to call the function by:

```
var data = Query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({(objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError!) -> Void in

})
```

This is different because of the swift update 1.2 which has changes with using optionals.

Comment: Thanks @RaVen, I've Xcode 6.3 and first approach worked

Comment: @PandurangYachwad mark my question as the right answer (the mark on the left side of the answer) thank you

Comment: I didn't mark any particular answer as right as both are correct. Anyways, I'll mark on of it as right.

Answer (score 3):

You should change `object` parameters type to array of AnyObject, and both parameters types to optional. So parameters should be `(object: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?)`.

Like below:

```
var data = Query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({(object: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

})
```